# How to change number(7,2) to varchar in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using Oracle 10g. I want to append # to all values in 'sal' column. To acomplish this first I'm trying to change  data type of 'sal' column from numeric to varchar but getting following error 
[image]

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use `modify`  keyword instead of your second `alter`  .

```
alter table
   emp
modify
(
   sal    varchar2(10)
);
```

When modifying a tables column datatype , you  need to use `modify` keyword.

Of course, you must deal with existing column data.  When modifying a tables column datatype you may want to export the rows, redefine the table and then re-import you data.

In this you would need to follow these steps to alter a column data type:

1. Create the new column at the end of the table.
2. Run an update to populate the new table column
3. Drop the old table column
4. Re-name the new column to the original column name

Comment: This works but giving error 'ERROR at line 5:
ORA-01439: column to be modified must be empty to change datatype'

Comment: @Serious : See the edit.The error is coming because you already have data in that table.

Answer (score 3):

It does not seem a smart idea to take a perfectly good number and ruin in for the rest of the user by appending a piece of string.
Just add the string on the select directly or through a view?

Something like:

```
SQL> create view emp_horked 
     as 
     select ename, sal, sal || '#' hash, to_char(SAL,'9999.99') || '#' sal_padded  
       from emp;

View created.

SQL> select * from emp_horked where rownum < 5;

ENAME             SAL HASH                                      SAL_PADDE
---------- ---------- ----------------------------------------- ---------
SMITH             800 800#                                        800.00#
ALLEN            1600 1600#                                      1600.00#
WARD             1250 1250#                                      1250.00#
JONES            2975 2975#                                      2975.00#
```

[More on format models](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00210) for `to_char`

Comment: What is `to_char(SAL,'9999.99') || '#' sal_padded` for ?

Comment: I meant what is use of last column ?

Comment: The last column attempts to address your request: " I want to append # to all values in 'sal' column." I guess I misunderstood the question. The way I read it you wanted to change it to varchar in order to add the "#" character to it. It seemed odd and seemed it would diminish the usefulness of the data. Now I'm thinking you picked an unfortunate example. I had a customer once who had 6-byte numeric order numbers and wanted to stored more values while retaining the 6 columns. So they wanted to change to varchar to be able to add alpha chars to the sequencing. That seemed reasonable.